# Select Variable Array Name From Another Variable

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Having multiple arrays as example:

```
Dim Common() As String = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"}
Dim Browser() As String = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"}
Dim AddedItems() As String = {"item6", "item7", "item8", "item9"}
...
```

A string (getItem) will be set to one of the above listed array names as such:
`Dim getItem As String = "Browser"`

How can this be used to pull the appropriate arrays list?
Something similar to the below:

```
For Each listItem As String In {getItem}
'Do this...
Next
```

This would need to output to the array items "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"

Can this be done in VB NET?

Comment: Please stop putting tags in the title and body of your questions and use tags properly. This question is not about VS so should not have the VS tag applied. If you had read the description of that tag then you'd know that it is NOT for questions about code written in VS; only for issues with the IDE.

Comment: The whole concept of what you're asking is wrong. You don't set a variable to the name of another variable. If you want to be able to identify the arrays by name then use a single `Dictionary(Of String, String())`, where the names are the keys and the arrays are the values. Alternatively, put the arrays into another array and identify them by index instead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the site asked for tags and I provided. I am new to this and I am using Visual Studio / Windows Forms App making this script. It seemed relevant to me. My apologies.

Comment: Read the descriptions of the tags to see whether they are relevant. They are provided for a reason. People watch those tags and get notifications when people use them and you are wasting people's time notifying them of questions that don't actually apply to that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting is not how things work. The closest option for doing things the right way is to use a `Dictionary` to identify the arrays by name:

```vb
Dim arrays As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From
        {
            {"Common", {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"}},
            {"Browser", {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"}},
            {"AddedItems", {"item6", "item7", "item8", "item9"}}
        }
```

You can then do this:

```vb
Dim arrayName = "Browser"

For Each item In arrays(arrayName)
    'Use item here.
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - Will read up more on this.

Comment: @MBF, there may be a better option too. I based this answer on the information provided in the question but if you edit it to provide a bit more specific background then we may be able to see a superior alternative.

Comment: I added use of a test for `dicWordLists.Containskey("Browser")`, because if "Browser" is misspelled, you will get an unhandled exception (error).   Try using "Browser1" as a key and see what happens.

Comment: @user94325897, I have provided an example that answers the question as asked. I'm not here to teach defensive programming techniques as part of every question I answer. That is a general principle that should be applied to anything and everything you do. Also, there's nothing specific in the question that indicates that an invalid key could be used, so there's nothing to indicate that a check for an invalid key is required. I answer the question that's asked. If that leads to another question then I will answer that too, but I won't assume that it's required.

Comment: @user94325897, also, if I was going to allow for an invalid key, I'd tend to use `TryGetValue`, as I commented on your answer. That will do the check and get the value if the key is valid in the one operation. Only use `ContainsKey` if you only want to know if the key is valid but don't actually want to use the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to frontload everything using a one-step injection of all the string arrays into the dictionary, and rather, want to add dictionary elements sequentially using the `.Add()` command, you can use this approach:

```
Dim Common() As String = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"}
Dim Browser() As String = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"}
Dim AddedItems() As String = {"item6", "item7", "item8", "item9"}

'Define the dictionary
Dim dicWordLists As New Dictionary(Of String, String())
'Add string arrays to dictionary
dicWordLists.Add("Common", Common)
dicWordLists.Add("Browser", Browser)
dicWordLists.Add("AddedItems", AddedItems)

'Set the key="Browser"
Dim getString As String = "Browser1"

'First, test if key is in dictionary, and if key is found, fetch value the string array
If dicWordLists.ContainsKey(getString) Then
    Dim strArray() As String = dicWordLists(getString)
    'Loop though all elements in string array
    For Each item In strArray
        MsgBox(item)
    Next
End If
```

In cases when you need to process all the key entries in a dictionary, you can loop through all the keys using the following:

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String()) In dicWordLists
  Dim strArray1() As String = kvp.Value
  For Each item In strArray1
     MsgBox(item)
  Next
Next
```

Comment: You don't loop through the keys of a `Dictionary` looking for a match. the whole point of a `Dictionary` is that it does a lookup, i.e. you provide the key and it provides the corresponding value.

Comment: Agree, you would loop when you need to process all the keys. in the dictionary.  See modified answer.

Comment: While using `ContainsKey` in that scenario is not necessarily wrong, you should use `TryGetValue` to do the check and get the value in one operation.